# Python - Trouble printing to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, printing, duplicates

My code seems to be outputting the list I want, however, when I try printing the list to CSV I do not get the same result on the .csv file for some reason. I am sure there's something not right at the end of my code. Could anyone please shed some light? Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('microRuleSet-row.csv')
deduplicated_list = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for item in row:
        if item not in deduplicated_list:
            deduplicated_list.append(item)
    print(deduplicated_list)
df.to_csv('microRuleSet-row-noDupes.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: you're not doing anything with `deduplicated_list` after you `print()` it. i don't know what you meant to do with it, but i imagine you'd put it into a new DataFrame then output that new DataFrame to a CSV file, not the unmodified original `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used pandas before. But it looks like you are outputting to csv the original microRuleSet-row.csv that you loaded.
You have to export the deduplicated_list to csv.
OK so each row must have no duplicated items. This code will do that.
The first (header) row is now numbered 0 to 5. This can be changed to to the original heading, and adding placeholders for the extra empty csv cells.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('microRuleSet-row.csv')
no_duplicates_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_row = []
    for item in row:
        if item not in new_row:
            new_row.append(item)
    no_duplicates_list.append(new_row)
print(no_duplicates_list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(no_duplicates_list)
df2.to_csv('microRuleSet-row-noDupes.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I have added that right after the last print that outputs to the screen, however, when I do add the code above, I only get the first column printed correctly joining half of the second column at the bottom of the first and it stops. It does not print the rest on the file.

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for the attention to this. Unfortunately, when running this proposed code above, I still get the columns in each row duplicated.
```
  National League Year      record   Player1            Player2            Player3            Player4            Player5            Player6
 National League of 1981  795  Kevin Millar       Kevin Millar       Jeff Fiorentino    Jeff Fiorentino 
 National League of 1983  442  Scott Williamson   Scott Williamson   Kevin Millar       Kevin Millar
 National League of 1985  623  Adam Stern      Adam Stern         Kris Benson        Kris Benson```

Comment: `| National League Year  | record | Player1 | Player2 | Player3 | Player4 | Player5 | Player6 | <br>
| National League of 1981 | 795  | Kevin Millar | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino  | Jeff Fiorentino  | Corey Patterson  | Corey Patterson  |
| National League of 1982 | 159  | Kevin Millar | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino  | Jeff Fiorentino  | Corey Patterson  | Corey Patterson  |
| National League of 1983 | 442  | Scott Williamson | Scott Williamson | Kevin Millar         `

Comment: Can you open the microdataset in notepad.  And show us the first 3 or 4 rows. So i can see what you are loading.

Comment: Sure, here it is:
National League Year,record,Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5,Player6,Player7
National League of 1981,795,Kevin Millar,Kevin Millar,Jeff Fiorentino,Jeff Fiorentino,Corey Patterson,Corey Patterson,Hayden Penn
National League of 1982,159,Kevin Millar,Kevin Millar,Jeff Fiorentino,Jeff Fiorentino,Corey Patterson,Corey Patterson,Hayden Penn
National League of 1983,442,Scott Williamson,Scott Williamson,Kevin Millar,Kevin Millar,Jeff Fiorentino,Jeff Fiorentino,Corey Patterson

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could add all this and SO allowed me to keep its formatting. I have tried putting as coding using the quotes, didn't work.

Comment: OK so you want the duplicated names stripped out of each row (why are the duplicated?). The first row would not work well any more as it would have player1 to player 7 in the headings - this would not work so good once the duplicated names in each row are stripped out.

Comment: That's fine, we can remove the first row. Values are duplicated because that is a csv I have gotten from work as I am trying to reduce this as much as I can for sake of simplicity. But I have hundreds of rows and hundreds of columns. The data is a mockup.

Comment: ```| National League of 1981 | 795  | Kevin Millar | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino  | Jeff Fiorentino  | Corey Patterson  | Corey Patterson  | 
| National League of 1982 | 159  | Kevin Millar | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino  | Jeff Fiorentino  | Corey Patterson  | Corey Patterson  | 
| National League of 1983 | 442  | Scott Williamson | Scott Williamson | Kevin Millar```

Comment: Ok so does my updated code work for what you want now.  I edited it a few hours ago. Its works for me - I installed pandas and made a csv from the data you posted.

Comment: Yes!!!!! Thank you so very much. I appreciate sticking with me on this. Definitely worked. You're the best. Unfortunately they don't let me up vote. But if there was tons of up votes, I would hit it.

Comment: Im Happy to help.

Comment: One last question. It seems that if a set of numbers become part of this list, it throws the whole thing off, is that a fact? Just curious.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. but if a row has multiple identical numbers then that row would strip the duplicates out.  You for example might then have some rows with 4 items and other rows with 10 items - this would affect the csv output I guess. A fix would be to add blank placeholders at the end of each row to pad it out to the original number of columns.

Comment: For example, I have added this to the first line:
`| 3242342 | 3242342 | 2341324142 | 2341324142 | Paul Bako | Paul Bako | Aubrey Huff | Aubrey Huff | 12328546 | 12328546 `
and kept the rest from the second line on... the code freaked out lol

Comment: I don't know what you mean by code freaked out. Its doesn't help me to fix anything that is not correct. I added that line after the Header line (National Leage year etc) - It still worked for me.

Comment: yeah, I got something like this in the first line...
`0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ......
National League of 1981 | 795 | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino | Corey Patterson | Hayden Penn |
National League of 1982 | 159 | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino | Corey Patterson | Hayden Penn |
National League of 1983 | 442 | Scott Williamson | Kevin Millar | Jeff Fiorentino | Corey Patterson |
National League of 1984 | 7119 | Adam Donachie | Paul Bako | Aubrey Huff | Freddie Bynum |` the first line only went from 0 to 15k columns
and on the print out on the console thousands of nan, nan, ...

Comment: also, do you mind if I start a new thread on this, it's getting quite long. I can also try to place the output there unless you know what happened.

Comment: Sure. A new thread.  Perhaps email me your faux data so i have exactly the same to work with. Now i understand what you want.

Comment: Ok, sent you the code and the data to ur hotmail. Cheers.